# hook for lostpassword form

Tags: hooks, wp-login-form

Im trying to add captcha to my remember `lost password` form:

I've added the input with the `lostpassword_form` hook and is ok.
now in the processing I need to add a error when captcha is invalid:

```
 add_action( 'lostpassword_post', 'processCaptcha' );

 public function processCaptcha()
 {
     if($_POST['captcha']!=$captcha){
       global $errors;     
       $errors->add('invalid', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: invalid captcha.'));
     }
 }
```

When I try to catch the `$error` with empty or invalid username/email shows:

```
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

What happen if you use this instead ?

```
public function processCaptcha()
 {
     if($_POST['captcha']!=$captcha){
       global $errors;     
       $errors->add('invalid', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: invalid captcha.');
     }
 }
```