# How to add Wp_error using lostpassword_post hook when validating custom field?

Tags: password

I have added a custom field(captcha) in lostpassword form using `lostpassword_form` hook. But when i am going to validate this field using `lostpassword_post` hook i can not add a wp_error.
i tried [hook for lostpassword form](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51255/hook-for-lostpassword-form) also tried `$errors = new WP_Error();` in place of `global $errors;` But no luck.

I DO NOT want to

1. die script with a error message. eg. `wp_die('error');`
2. Redirect to same url with a error argument then catch that argument with GET method and show a message accordingly.

Is there a way to add wp_error? If not why WordPress did not add `do_action( 'lostpassword_post', $errors );` instead of `do_action( 'lostpassword_post' );`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**As of WordPress 4.4**, the action `lostpassword_post` passes the `$errors` object:

```
function wpse_185243_lastpassword_post( $errors ) {
    if ( ! $captcha_valid /* The result of your captcha */ ) {
        $errors->add( 'invalid_captcha', '<strong>ERROR:</strong> Try again sonny.' );
    }
}

add_action( 'lostpassword_post', 'wpse_185243_lastpassword_post' );
```

---

**Pre 4.4 legacy answer**

Here's the relevant code you're referring to (`retrieve_password()` in `wp-login.php`):

```
function retrieve_password() {
    $errors = new WP_Error();

    // Some error checking

    do_action( 'lostpassword_post' );

    if ( $errors->get_error_code() )
        return $errors;


    // Some more code

    /**
     * Filter whether to allow a password to be reset.
     *
     * @since 2.7.0
     *
     * @param bool true           Whether to allow the password to be reset. Default true.
     * @param int  $user_data->ID The ID of the user attempting to reset a password.
     */
    $allow = apply_filters( 'allow_password_reset', true, $user_data->ID );

    if ( ! $allow )
        return new WP_Error('no_password_reset', __('Password reset is not allowed for this user'));
    else if ( is_wp_error($allow) )
        return $allow;
}
```

As you say, there's no way to get hold of `$errors` (it's a local variable and is never passed to a filter/action - might be worth filing a feature request in a trac ticket).

However, it appears you can use `allow_password_reset` to return a new `WP_Error`, and WordPress will handle it in the same way as a core error:

```
function wpse_185243_lost_password_captcha( $result, $user_id ) {   
    if ( ! $captcha_valid /* The result of your captcha */ ) {
        $result = new WP_Error( 'invalid_captcha', '<strong>ERROR:</strong> Try again sonny.' );
    }

    return $result;
}

add_filter( 'allow_password_reset', 'wpse_185243_lost_password_captcha', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your details answer @thedeadmedic i am not well familiar will wordpress trac ticket. Can you do that for me? also please advice some links where i can know something about wordpress trac ticket system.

Comment: I've [submitted a ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32116). If you want to learn how, [start here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/working-with-trac/opening-a-ticket/).

Comment: Thank you again @TheDeadMedic but why `do_action_ref_array( 'lostpassword_post', array( &$errors ) );` why not `do_action( 'lostpassword_post', $errors );` My knowledge is less about this that's why asking. don't take it other ways.

Comment: In PHP 4 it was the only way to [pass objects by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), but now that WP requires PHP 5 it's no longer (technically) required - I used it to stay in line with legacy code, but the WP devs might deem it pointless and simply use `do_action`

Comment: +1 This is a good question and good answer that needs to have received more upvotes imo.